# avoid using multiple # (number signs) in R

Tags: r

I have a basic question that I can't find an answer to: in R th # symbol can be used to "hide" a line, but what if you wan't to hide a lot of lines, like a complete paragraph? Of course I could put # in front of every line but this takes a lot of work, and even more to remove them from time to time.

So instead of

```
#a=1
#b=2
#c=3
#d=4
```

I would like to do something like

```
#a=1
 b=2
 c=3
#d=4
```

which should also hide b and c.

Maybe I didn't use the right search terms in google and I'm sorry if that's the case.

Thank you!

Comment: If you're using RStudio as your IDE, you can just use Ctrl + Shift + c to comment and un-comment selected blocks of code.

Comment: Yes, the other post also answers my question, I'm sorry for the duplicate (although it's a hard one to find and posted 4 years ago). And thanks ananda, that's the useful comment I needed!